# How to add input data to CSV file in PHP?

Tags: php, forms, csv, input

I need to add form input data from an array to a **CSV** file in **PHP**.

I tried to add the data with **foreach** function but the data didn't appear in the **CSV** file with the following code:

```
$values = [
    'orderperson',
    'address',
    'postnumber',
    'city',
    'phone',
    'email'
];

$fh = fopen("file.csv", "w");
foreach($values as $info) {
    fputcsv($fh, $_POST[$info]);
}
```

If I'm correct what I'm trying to accomplish here puts all the data in one row? How I can add the data in the file like that there's only one element of array in one row like this:

1 orderperson
2 address
3 postnumber

and not like 1 orderperson 2 address 3 postnumber

Answer (score 1, accepted):

fputcsv() delimiter must be a single character

```
$fh = fopen("file.csv", "w");
$delimiter = ',';
fputcsv($fh, $values, $delimiter);
```

alternatively, you can try this:

```
$values = [
'orderperson',
'address',
'postnumber',
'city',
'phone',
'email'
];

$path = 'file.csv';
$handle = fopen($path, 'w+');
foreach($values as $value) {
    fwrite($handle, $value . ',' . PHP_EOL);
}
fclose($handle);
```

You can later either trim last comma or use count() and avoid adding delimiter for the last element in array.

---

If, on the other hand, you do not wish to have comma, but new lines as a separation (but, that is no longer CSV file!!), you can replace above fwrite() line with this:

```
fwrite($handle, $value . PHP_EOL);
```

Comment: Don't I need $_POST there somewhere cause those values are input data?

Comment: Well, without knowing your input side, there is no way to tell that. Anyway, you can replace $values array with your $_POST input, of course! This is an answer to your question *how to write your values per new line*, not how to handle input.

Answer (score 0):

Alright. You appear to be on the right path. If you intend to put every entry in the $values array on a new line in the resultant .csv file, do the following:

1. Create a function to merge the fields set in the $data array with incoming $_POST data

```php
$postToCsv = function (array $fields, array $super) {
  return array_map(function ($field, $val) {
    return array($field, $val);
  }, $fields, $super);
};
```

2. Modify the loop to use the function in the snippet above.

```php
foreach ($postToCsv($values, $_POST) as $field) {
  fputcsv($fh, $field);
}
```

Also, remember to close the file operation.

```php
fclose($fh);
```